# How much does each rotation coarse adjustment move the stage in a microscope?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology

I've been working with microscopes lately and have been trying to think of a way to somehow find out a way to some how find out a way to relate the rotaions of fine adjustment to coarse adjustment.
The main idea is to figure out how many centimeters the fine adjustment moves the stage, then compare the same thing for coarse adjustment.

Comment: This is unanswerable unless you specify the particular model of microscope as there are tens of thousands of different models with their own specifications. You would also need to show your research in alignment with the [help]'s requirement. It would be great if you'd also tell us the purpose of the question and how it relates to biology, as it seems to be a question of engineering at present.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction manual for the microscope would help greatly.  But there is a simple method that should tell you what you need to know with modest precision.  Use micrometers (the instrument, not the unit) to measure the thickness of a microscrope slide.  Mark the top and bottom sides of the slide with an expo marker.  Put the slide in the slide holder firmly, and focus on the bottom of the slide first ... then count how many times you need to turn the knob to focus on the top.